# Wordpress load external scripts with local fallback

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong! I want the function to return a freshly-created variable with a true/false value that I can use to see if we've got the file or not.

```
// Check to make sure external files are available
function checklink ( $link, $checkname ) { 
    $try_url = @fopen( $link,'r' );
    if( $try_url !== false ) { return $$checkname; } 
}

var_dump( checklink( 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js', 'jqueryOK' ) ); // NULL
```

I've tried setting $checkname to true or false, adding an extra line to give it a value before return ... PHP 'knows' there is a variable $jqueryOK but says it's undefined.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

Decided to share the outcome, as this is often an overlooked thing in Wordpress - and am changing the title to reflect the task.

```
// Check to make sure external files are available
function checklink ($link) { 
return( bool )@fopen( $link, 'r' );
}

function thatwomanuk_external_scripts()
{
if ($GLOBALS['pagenow'] != 'wp-login.php' && !is_admin()) {

// jquery
    $link = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js';
    if( checklink( $link ) ) { // true - otherwise, Wordpress will load its own     
        wp_deregister_script('jquery'); // remove jQuery v1
        wp_register_script('jquery', $link, array(), '3.3.1', true); // add jQuery v3
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_script_add_data( 'jquery', array( 'integrity', 'crossorigin' ), array( 'sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=', 'anonymous' ) );
    }   
// google fonts
    $link = 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,400i,500|Ubuntu:300,400,400i,500&amp;subset=latin-ext';
    $fallback = get_template_directory_uri() . '/fonts/thatwoman-fonts-min.css';
    if( checklink( $link ) ) {  
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-google-fonts', $link, false ); 
    } else {    
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-google-fonts', $fallback, false ); 
    }   
// touch events library
    $link = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-touch-events/1.0.5/jquery.mobile-events.js';
    $fallback = get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lib/jquery.mobile-events.min.js';
    if( checklink( $link ) ) {          
        wp_register_script('thatwoman-touch-events', $link, array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.5', true);
    } else {            
        wp_register_script('thatwoman-touch-events', $fallback, array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.5', true);
    }
    wp_enqueue_script('thatwoman-touch-events');
}
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'thatwomanuk_external_scripts' );
```

Thanks to @u_mulder for making me see sense.

Comment: Double `$$` is creating problem. change it to `if( $try_url !== false ) { return $checkname; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simplify your function to:

```
// Check to make sure external files are available
function checklink ($link) { 
    return (bool)@fopen( $link,'r');
}
```

After that in your code:

```
$link1Available = checklink($link1);
$link2Available = checklink($link2);
// etc
```

Or as an array:

```
$links = ['link1', 'link2', 'link3'];
$linksAvailable = [];
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $linksAvailable[$link] = checklink($link);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's not often I overcomplicate my PHP! I've decided to move the script loaders out of the function they were in (due to vars losing value) and handle all the external sources together as you have outlined above.This way, I don't have to pass vars from function to function and it's easy to see what we're doing. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to have a **local fallback for a CDN loaded js file**, you can use [wp_scripts()->add_inline_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_scripts/add_inline_script/) which was added in 4.5, to add a js check if the library was loaded, see my detailed answer on wordpress.stackexchange [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/315446/34517).

The short version:

You can use [wp_scripts()->add_inline_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_scripts/add_inline_script/), which will append a js script to an enqueued script, no questions asked, no code problems checked (there is a wrapper function [wp_add_inline_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/) that does checks but does not permit `</script>` tags, even encoded).

This is a working example

```
function _enqueue_my_scripts() {
  // the normal enqueue
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-cdn', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' );
  // our custom code which will check for the existance of jQuery (in this case)
  wp_scripts()->add_inline_script( 'jquery-cdn',
    "window.jQuery || document.write('<script src=\"".get_template_directory_uri() ."/js/jQuery.js\">\\x3C/script>')", 'after');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', '_enqueue_my_scripts', 100);
```

which will give you

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.Swiper || document.write('<script src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/wp-theme/js/jQuery.js">\x3C/script>')
</script>
```

in your HTML.

Replace 'window.jQuery' and '/js/jQuery.js' according to your needs but don't touch the rest of the line as it is meant to pass through the correct line to the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You have double $$ sign in return statement:

```
if( $try_url !== false ) { return $$checkname; }
```

Comment: Yes - is that not the right way to create a new variable name? I can't just return $checkname because I need a unique identifier each time I call the function.

Comment: Syntax you used $$ is called variable variable http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php. Hence your script behaves incorrectly.

Comment: I thought a variable variable was what I needed. If I leave the return value as $checked, I get the string 'jqueryOK' which is what I put into the function. How should I then turn that string into a named variable, which can be used to see whether the file was available? It's got to be unique & identifiable, as there are lots of external scripts to check.